# converting a tensorflow model to coreml with queue runner

Tags: tensorflow, coreml

I want to convert a very simple tensorflow model to coreml model with "tfcoreml". The problem is that when Im using queue runner for efficient training, I get error during conversion.

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
```

queue runner based generator provides [X , Y] at the same time! and the corresponding name is "nextGenerator" as therefore "nextGenerator:0" is the corresponding tensor.
My question is how can I handle this issue and just get int input correspondent?